# Find row indices from two 2d arrays with close values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `a`

```
a = np.array([[4, 4],
              [5, 4],
              [6, 4],
              [4, 5],
              [5, 5],
              [6, 5],              
              [4, 6],
              [5, 6],
              [6, 6]])
```

and an array `b`

```
b = np.array([[4.001,4], 
              [8.001,4],
              [5,4.0003],
              [5.9999,5]])
```

I want to find the indices of `a` that have values very close to those of `b`. If the `b` array has the exact same values as the values in `a` I can use the following code.

```
np.where((a==b[:,None]).all(-1))[1]
```

For clarity; I would like the code to return the following: `[0,1,5]`
These are the indices of a that are very close to the rows in b. The value in `b` with the value`[8.001,4]` is discarded as it is not in `a`.
I think combining the code above with np.allclose() would fix it, however I can't seem to figure out how to do this, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `==`, use `np.linalg.norm` on `a - b[:, np.newaxis]` to get the distance of each row in `a` to each row in `b`.

If `a` and `b` have many rows, this will use lots of memory: e.g., if each has 10,000 rows, the `vecdiff` array below would be 10,000-by-10,000, or 100,000,000 elements; using doubles this is 800MB.

```py
In [50]: a = np.array([[4, 4], 
    ...:               [5, 4], 
    ...:               [6, 4], 
    ...:               [4, 5], 
    ...:               [5, 5], 
    ...:               [6, 5],               
    ...:               [4, 6], 
    ...:               [5, 6], 
    ...:               [6, 6]]) 
    ...:                                                                        

In [51]: b = np.array([[4.001,4],  
    ...:               [8.001,4], 
    ...:               [5,4.0003], 
    ...:               [5.9999,5]])                                             

In [52]: vecdist = np.linalg.norm(a - b[:, np.newaxis], axis=-1)                

In [53]: closeidx = np.flatnonzero(vecdist.min(axis=0) < 1e-2)                  

In [54]: print(closeidx)                                                        
[0 1 5]
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem, 'a' will reach a maximum length of a 1000 rows and 'b' will have a maximum length of 12 rows. My main concern would rather be speed as I will have to run this part of the code up to 1e6 times.